# Android application with different languages but same place

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an application with different languages to cater for the need of different people in the same city. However, as I found out from android developer, Google Play differentiates languages according to locale. Is there any way to solve this problem apart from allowing users to choose the language on the application?

Comment: users can display app in their language if your app supports it and if their phone language is their native one.

Comment: blueware is right, the language displayed within your App depends on the users locale settings on his phone... wherever he is located. You can test it by changing your own locale on your debug device.